# Replace innerHTML of divs with same class based on content

Tags: javascript

I am trying to only replace the content of the div with the "replace this".

The content of each div is dynamically created, so i have to check which class needs to be changed. I tried it with a for-loop and so far I am getting the right div but having trouble changing its content. The main problem is that they all have the same class. How can I put the new text into the correct div without changing the others?

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("class_name");
var teststring = "rep";

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (x[i].toString().indexOf(teststring) > 0) {
    this.innerHTML = "text3";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="class_name">
  text1
</div>
<div class="class_name">
  text2
</div>
<div class="class_name">
  replace this
</div>
```

Comment: difference between the 'right' and 'wrong' div? is it the last one? is it the third?

Comment: `x[i].innerHTML = "text3";`?

Comment: in this case the "right" div has the substring "rep", the wrong ones dont. As in "find all classes with the content 'replace this' and replace their content with 'text3'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the variable with `let` in the for loop which will create it's own scope within curly braces (`{...}`). Instead of using `this`, use the current element with `x[i]`. `x[i]` refers to the element itself, you have to take the content from it.

I will prefer `textcontent` instead of `innerHTML`

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("class_name");
var teststring = "rep";

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (x[i].textContent.indexOf(teststring) > 0) {
    x[i].textContent = "text3";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="class_name">
  text1
</div>
<div class="class_name">
  text2
</div>
<div class="class_name">
  replace this
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `x[i].innerHTML` not `this.innerHTML`

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("class_name");
var teststring = "rep";

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i].innerHTML.indexOf(teststring) !== -1) {
    x[i].innerHTML = "text3";
}
}
```

**DEMO**
https://jsfiddle.net/0cmz4pvk/5/